# Is it possible to read code of a C++ library and modify it?

Tags: c++

A bit of a simple question, though the answer may not be. I am fairly new to C++ and was wondering if it was possible to open a C++ library and see it's code. It sounds like a potentially risky move to accidentally change the core code of the library, but I would still like to see if it is possible. Thank you!

Comment: Which library, the source for the stdlib implementation is usually open source and many c++ libs are opensource already

Comment: no if all you have is the compiled binary. For template library, all the code are already in the header files.

Comment: @yngum decompilers, apparently they work pretty well now

Comment: @aaronman I'm not sure if a decompiler is what he's looking for... the easiest thing to do would be to look at the open source implementations if you're looking to learn. On my system, at least, all I have is compiled binaries. Edit: ah, didn't see that first comment was yours too.

Comment: @rogaos that's why I left the first comment, boost is the most highly regarded c++ lib and it's open source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are too kinds of libraries that C++ can use:

- compiled to binary libraries which are linked with linker to your
  executable;
- headers-only libraries which are just included with    `include` into
  your source code

You can "open" headers of headers-only libraries and modify code if you wish (but not recommended).

Also many compiled libraries are open source. You can open source files there.  If you want to modify such library, you will need to compile it and link your executable against this modified version.

Comment: Editing the code would be an indirect way.

Answer (score -2):

Yes it s possible to open a c++ library and see its code.

If you want to make changes to any functionality simply create your own version of it giving it a different name, or if you want to add functionality just simply extend the class you are interested in. (read up on inheritance for this).